# Django field cleaning ValidationErrors don't prevent form from processing

Tags: django, forms, validation, django-forms, data-cleaning

I'm designing a Django form with custom cleaning methods for both fields, and the form itself.

Ideally, I'd love for my form to stop processing and throw an error if my fields don't validate. However, the custom clean() method that I wrote for my form runs even when fields throw ValidationErrors.

Here's an example:

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import User

class BasicsForm(forms.Form):

    email = forms.EmailField(label='E-mail address', max_length=128)

    def clean_email(self):

            email = self.cleaned_data['email']

            if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                raise forms.ValidationError("E-mail is already taken.")

            return email

    def clean(self):

            # Call the parent clean method
            cleaned_data = super().clean()

            email = cleaned_data.get('email')

            u = User(email=email)
            u.save()
```

If I attempt to submit the above form with an invalid e-mail address (for example, an e-mail already registered on the site, which will raise the ValidationError within clean_email), I get an IntegrityError that says I can't add a NULL e-mail to my database. What's happening is that even though clean_email catches an error, the lines that create a user in my clean() method (i.e., `u = User(email=email)` and `u.save()`) still run.

How do I make it so that if my clean_email() method catches an error, clean() doesn't run, and my form instead shows the error thrown by clean_email()?

Comment: The idea of the clean method is to return cleaned_data, not to save an object, that should be done in the view.

Comment: That makes sense — very helpful. Thank you, Guillermo! For those who are curious on more detail: this essentially means that I should be calling my u = User(email=email) line after form.is_valid() in my views.py file, rather than doing the processing within forms.py.